# Post images are not displayed in media library

Tags: posts, images, media, media-library, media-settings

I use an image for a page that is uploaded back in 2014 up until now and back then I uploaded few images as well. But when I looked into the library, I could only find the images that are uploaded this year (both in use as well as not used). And yet, in the page editor the thumbnail of that image is still being displayed although I can't select it when I open the media selector.

All images that I have uploaded until now are in folder wp-content/uploads/ as well. Does someone know what is happening?

Comment: Is the image being displayed? What's this image's `src`? Use "Inspect" in your browser's right-click context menu to find its location on your server.

Comment: Ah stop, now I get it. In your media library the old images are not being displayed, right? Then you might rephrase your question for clarification and tag it with `media-library`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is exactly what I mean. The images are also working perfectly on the website and I can find them on my server as well. The only problem is that they are not displayed in media-library panel.